# CSV header_converters: :symbol giving inconsistent results

Tags: ruby, csv

Using the Ruby CSV `for_each` with `headers: true, header_converters: :symbol` I'm having trouble predicting what the resulting header symbols will be. Sometimes it just downcases and replaces spaces with underscores, so `"Name"` becomes `:name`, but sometimes it prefixes and postfixes the symbol with underscores, so `"Latitude"` becomes `:_latitude_`.

It's a fairly minor irritation -- I can just look at the converted row and see what the headers are, but I'd like to understand why it's happening (and whether I can easily stop it). I've looked for documentation on `header_converters: :symbol` but can only find that it converts the headers to symbols (which I knew), not *how* it does the conversion.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've worked out what was happening. The editor I was using to inspect the source CSV file was masking some spurious spaces, which the CSV library was converting to the underscores. What I really need to do is work out how to persuade `header_converters` to strip whitespace before converting.

Comment: Did the same to  me :) Nice catch.